# react-redux could not find 'store' ... in customizing scratch-gui

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, connect

I have followed the way of implementing scratch-www to customize my own scratch3.0 embedded web.

I just wanted to make my starting page to the scratch editor, but after giving out all the providers(store provider and Intl-provider) the code gives me 'could not find 'store'... error'

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(LocalizationWrapper)". Either wrap the root component in a  or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(LocalizationWrapper)".

The LocalizationWrapper mentioned above is a HOC inside of the scratch-gui library.
I have attached my code below, can anyone help with my situation, please?

```js
// project-view.jsx
const React = require('react');
const injectIntl = require('react-intl').injectIntl;
const GUI = require('scratch-gui');
const IntlGUI = injectIntl(GUI.default);


class Preview extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectId: 0
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <IntlGUI
                projectId={this.state.projectId}
            />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

module.exports.View = Preview;
GUI.setAppElement(document.getElementById('app'));
module.exports.initGuiState = guiInitialState => {
    return GUI.initPlayer(guiInitialState);
}
module.exports.guiReducers = GUI.guiReducers;
module.exports.guiInitialState = GUI.guiInitialState;
module.exports.guiMiddleware = GUI.guiMiddleware;
module.exports.initLocale = GUI.initLocale;
module.exports.localesInitialState = GUI.localesInitialState;
```

code in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const redux = require('redux');
const thunk = require('redux-thunk').default;
const Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const IntlProvider = require('react-intl').IntlProvider;
const ProjectView = require('./views/project/project-view.jsx');

    let locale = window._locale || 'en';
    const reducer = {
        ...ProjectView.guiReducers
    };

    const reducers = redux.combineReducers(reducer);

    const initState = {
        locales: ProjectView.initLocale(ProjectView.localesInitialState, locale),
        scratchGui: ProjectView.initGuiState(ProjectView.guiInitialState)
    };

    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || redux.compose;
    const enhancers = composeEnhancers(
        redux.applyMiddleware(thunk),
        ProjectView.guiMiddleware
    );

    const store = redux.createStore(
        reducers,
        initState,
        enhancers
    );

    const messages = {};

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}> 
            <IntlProvider 
                locale={locale}
                messages={messages}
            >
                <ProjectView.View />
            </IntlProvider>
        </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call AppStateHOC on GUI, which creates separate store and wraps a Provider on GUI. AppStateHOC is also exported from scratch-gui module, and you could see the source code for detail.

```
import GUI, { AppStateHOC } from 'scratch-gui';

// use this instead of raw GUI
const WrappedGUI = AppStateHOC(GUI);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been struggled for quite a while, and then solved it in exactly the same way as yours!. It is working fine now